# For loop alternative choices for pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I need to clean and transpose a dataframe coming from excel with botanical data. Here is an csv extract :

```
Transect    Espèce  Exigence    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37
1   Acer pseudoplatanus     Sylvatique  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                                           
1   Agrimonia eupatoria Prairiale   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0                                           
1   Agrostis stolonifera    Sylvatique  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                                           
1   Anagallis arvensis  Pionnière   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                                           
1   Apicaceae sp.   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                                           
1   Cirsium vulgare Rudérale    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                                           
1   Clematis vitalba    Sylvatique calcicole    0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0                                           
1   Odontites vernus    Hémiparasite    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                                           
1   Ombellifère sp. 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                                           
1   Sanguisorba minor   Pelouse calcicole   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0                                           
2   Avenula pubescens   Prairiale calcicole 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                   
2   Circaea lutetiana   Sylvatique  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                   
2   Cirsium arvense     Rudérale    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0                   
2   Lysimachia arvensis     Pionnière   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                   
2   Trifolium repens    Prairiale   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                   
2   Trifolium sp.   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                   
2   Ulex europaeus  Landicole   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0                   
3   Primula veris   Prairiale   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
3   Prunella vulgaris   Prairiale   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
3   Prunus avium    Sylvatique  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
3   Prunus mahaleb  Sylvatique calcicole    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   
3   Prunus spinosa  Sylvatique  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   
3   Rubus sp    Rudérale    0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   
3   Senecio vulgaris    Rudérale    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
3   Sinapis arvensis    Pionnière calcicole 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
3   Trifolium sp.   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
3   Ulex europaeus  Landicole   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The idea is to create a dataframe for each unique value of "Transect" and to use "Exigence" to sum data for each column afterward then transpose the dataframe. This code must be reusable on other dataframes where there "Exigence" column has another name and where more columns exist between it and the "Transect" column.

I made a for loop but I would like to create a cleaner code. I tried to understand how to use lambda functions to do so and/or map/reduce/filter but I'm a bit lost.

Here is my code so far :

```
def stat_pl(df,col):
    # splitting df in multiple dataframes on Transect unique values
    dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Transect')))
    #Empty dictionary for resulting dataframes
    dfr = {}
    n = df.Transect.max()
    for i in range(n):
        # selecting 1 dataframe
        ext=dfs[i+1]
        # dropping nan and useless columns
        ext=ext.dropna(axis=1)
        col_list=list()
        col_list.append(col)
        col_list.extend(list(ext.columns[ext.columns.get_loc(1):len(ext.columns) - 1].values))
        ext=ext[col_list]
        ext=ext.groupby(col).sum()
        ext.index.name = None
        ext=ext.transpose()
        ext.rename(columns = {0:'Sans exigence'}, inplace = True)
        ext.to_csv('t'+str(i+1)+'.csv')
        dfr[i] = ext
    return dfr
```

Comment: For a CSV file, there are very few commas. That makes it hard to actually read the columns: is the Exigence column an integer column, or a string column?

Answer (score 0):

> *I made a for loop but I would like to create a cleaner code. I tried to understand how to use lambda functions to do so and/or map/reduce/filter but I'm a bit lost.*

I would simply use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) :

```
def stat_pl(df, col):
    return {
        tr: (g.drop(columns="Transect")
             .pivot_table(columns=col, aggfunc="sum")
             .rename_axis(columns=None))
        for tr, g in (df.fillna({col: "Sans exigence"})
                      .drop(columns="Espèce").groupby("Transect"))
    }
```

Another variant (*maybe more efficient*) :

```
def stat_pl(df, col):
    piv = (
        df.fillna({col: "Sans exigence"}).drop(columns="Espèce")
            .pivot_table(index="Transect", columns=col, aggfunc="sum")
            .stack(0)
    )
    
    return {
        tr: piv.loc[tr].rename_axis(columns=None).dropna(how="all", axis=1)
        for tr in df["Transect"].unique()
    }
```

Output :

```
d = stat_pl(df, "Exigence")

for tr, sub_df in d.items():
    print(f"Transect: {tr}"); print(sub_df, end="\n"*2)
    # sub_df.to_csv(f"t{tr}.csv")# uncomment this line if needed
```

```
Transect: 1
    Hémiparasite  Pelouse calcicole  ...  Sylvatique  Sylvatique calcicole
1           0.00               0.00  ...        0.00                  0.00
10          0.00               0.00  ...        0.00                  0.00
..           ...                ...  ...         ...                   ...
8           0.00               0.00  ...        0.00                  0.00
9           0.00               0.00  ...        0.00                  0.00

[37 rows x 6 columns]

Transect: 2
    Landicole  Pionnière  ...  Sans exigence  Sylvatique
1        1.00       0.00  ...           0.00        0.00
10       1.00       0.00  ...           0.00        0.00
..        ...        ...  ...            ...         ...
8        0.00       0.00  ...           0.00        0.00
9        1.00       0.00  ...           0.00        0.00

[37 rows x 7 columns]

Transect: 3
    Landicole  Pionnière calcicole  ...  Sylvatique  Sylvatique calcicole
1        1.00                 0.00  ...        0.00                  0.00
10       0.00                 0.00  ...        0.00                  0.00
..        ...                  ...  ...         ...                   ...
8        0.00                 0.00  ...        0.00                  0.00
9        0.00                 0.00  ...        0.00                  0.00

[37 rows x 7 columns]
```

Used input :

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

tmp = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text_op),
      sep=r"(?<=[a-z.])\s+(?=[01])", engine="python")

def adjust(block, df=tmp):
    return (tmp.iloc[:, block].str.split("\s\s+", expand=True)
            .set_axis(df.columns[block].split(), axis=1))

df = adjust(0).join(adjust(1)).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much ! I modified a bit your code (nan values were not dropped correctly when I executed it)

```
def stat_pl(df, col):
df=df.fillna(-1)
df.loc[df.Exigence==0, 'Exigence']='Sans exigence'
piv = (
    df.drop(columns="Espèce")
        .pivot_table(index="Transect", columns=col, aggfunc="sum")
        .stack(0)
)
piv = piv.loc[piv.Sylvatique >= 0]
return {
    tr: piv.loc[tr].rename_axis(columns=None).dropna(how="all", axis=1)
    for tr in df["Transect"].unique()
}

d = stat_pl(df, col) for tr, sub_df in d.items():
     print(f"Transect: {tr}"); print(sub_df, end="\n"*2)
     sub_df.to_csv(f"t{tr}.csv")# uncomment this line if needed
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).